# group by nested and non nested fields in es

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

Hi i am trying to do group by nested and non nested fields.I want to do group by on 1 non nested fields(from_district) ,1 nested field(truck_number) and max on nested field(truck_number.score).

**Requirement** -: to get max score of each truck in all districts if truck is present in that district for a given sp_id
eg-:

```
District1 ,truck1, 0.9,
District2 ,truck1, 0.8,
District1 ,truck2, 1.8,
District2 ,truck3, 0.7,
District3 ,truck4, 1.7
```

Below is my mapping

```
{
  "sp_ranked_indent" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "from_district" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "sp_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "to_district" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "truck_ranking_document" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "score" : {
              "type" : "float"
            },
            "truck_number" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the query that i tried but it is not grouping by nested and non nested field and also the max truck score is incorrect

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "sp_id": [650128],
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "NESTED_AGG": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "truck_ranking_document"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "max_score": {
                    "max": {
                        "field": "truck_ranking_document.score"
                    }
                },
                "truck_numer": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "truck_ranking_document.truck_number.keyword",
                        "size": 10,
                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                        "order": [{
                            "_count": "desc"
                        }, {
                            "_key": "asc"
                        }]
                    }
                },
                "fromdistrictagg": {
                    "reverse_nested": {},
                    "aggregations": {
                        "fromDistrict": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "from_district",
                                "size": 10,
                                "min_doc_count": 1,
                                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                "order": [{
                                    "_count": "desc"
                                }, {
                                    "_key": "asc"
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done using term and nested aggregation. Below query will produce output in follwing format

```
  District1 
        Truck1
             Max score
        Truck2
             Max score
        Truck3
             Max score
  District2
        Truck1
             Max score
        Truck2
             Max score
        Truck3
             Max score
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "sp_id": [
        1
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "district": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "from_district",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "trucks": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "truck_ranking_document"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "truck_no": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "truck_ranking_document.truck_number.keyword",
                "size": 10
              },
              "aggs": {
                "max_score": {
                  "max": {
                    "field": "truck_ranking_document.score"
                  }
                },
                "select": {
                  "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                      "score": "max_score"
                    },
                    "script": "if(params.score>0) return true;"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "min_bucket_selector": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "trucks>truck_no._bucket_count"
            },
            "script": {
              "inline": "params.count != 0"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "district" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "District1",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "trucks" : {
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "truck_no" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "1",
                  "doc_count" : 1,
                  "max_score" : {
                    "value" : 2.0
                  }
                },
                {
                  "key" : "3",
                  "doc_count" : 1,
                  "max_score" : {
                    "value" : 3.0
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

**[Composite Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html)**

Composite aggregation response contains an after_key

```
"after_key" : {
        "district" : "District4"
      }
```

you need to use the after parameter to retrieve the next results

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
       "size": 100,
        "sources": [
          {
            "district": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "from_district"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "trucks": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "truck_ranking_document"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "truck_no": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "truck_ranking_document.truck_number.keyword",
                "size": 10
              },
              "aggs": {
                "max_score": {
                  "max": {
                    "field": "truck_ranking_document.score"
                  }
                },
                "select": {
                  "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                      "score": "max_score"
                    },
                    "script": "if(params.score>0) return true;"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks,but 1) it is considering the districts also where truck is not present and giving zero score for that district?...2) can we filter/ remove where max truck score is 0

Comment: thanks, the inner one is for max score >0 and what is the outer one for?...also can you let me know how to implement it in java buket selector

Comment: @deadlybeast If there are no buckets under a term. ie if a district has no truck with max_score greater than 0

Comment: @deadlybeast In java it should be something like Map<String, String> bucketsPathsMap = new HashMap<>();
        bucketsPathsMap.put("score", "max_score");
        Script script = new Script("params.score > 0");

   BucketSelectorPipelineAggregationBuilder bs =
                PipelineAggregatorBuilders.bucketSelector("select", bucketsPathsMap, script);
AggregationBuilders.subAggregation(bs);

Comment: it is not working when i am adding like below in java code.Response is coming as null .Should not i add it as sub agg after max ?.https://ideone.com/8Zical

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214671/discussion-between-jaspreet-chahal-and-deadly-beast).

Comment: the above query is taking around 2 s for 1000 parent doc and 500 nested doc within each of them ..is this behavious expected or is there some problem query/index/mapping

Comment: @deadlybeast few things you can do to improve speed. 1 remove unnecessary bucket selector (there are 2 remove what you don't need). 2.if you don't need docs make size as 0 in query

Comment: i have already removed outer bucket selector..and size is 0 in query already ..is the slowness due to bucket selector or doc size or index config?

Comment: @deadlybeast In config/elasticsearch.yml set bootstrap.memory_lock: true This disables memory swapping . If your query is still slow you need to use pagination. You need to use composite aggregation , i have updated the answer for it

Comment: i will check that memory lock..@jaspreet is truck_number not being keyword will slow aggs..as i have to apply truck_number.keyword in group by ..let me know your opinion..

Comment: @deadlybeast aggregations work only only numeric and keyword values. if truck_number is of type text it will throw error(ask to enable fielddata on text field). if it is numeric you don't need keyword. if text create a sub field with keyword type. If data is too much, you can try for pagination using composite aggregation